best idea for Multi-lingual email
Here's my dilemma.
I advertised my product on a website that supports multiple languages but when people purchase my product through that website, I'm notified about it in english. However, when I try to communicate with some customers, they never respond and I believe that may be because they used the website in their language (a language other than english) and expect communication in their language as well.
On my website, I support 10 different languages (with help from AI) and I want to communicate to my customers in all 10 languages without making it a burden to anyone.
I have looked at a few websites including this one for some help:
Best practice for multi-language mails?
Someone suggested doing side-by-side text in the email, but this doesn't look good on a mobile device.
I'm looking for some best examples that would help everyone.
The only thing I can think of for an email template is this:
English text follows

For french, click here
For Japanese, click here 
...
...
For spanish, click here 
 
Hello (name), 
Email in english...

Thanks whatever

But the issue with that is that people that want to read english would have to scroll past the first part about the languages.
Is there another way I can present an email in multiple languages to someone without placing an unnecessary burden?


Best is to get the user locale with the purchase so you can send accurate emails.

Are you sure that people don't respond because of the language problem? Otherwise keep it in English so you can deliver the message in the mail in a more direct and effective way.


You probably want to target the right language and keep the message catchy. That is really difficult to achieve and you will probably not get the full potential. An attempt however can be as follows:

Who is going to click if you don't know what the link has to offer? Instead of providing links in English, create short paragraphs per language in the target language. The idea is to keep it a few lines at most so more paragraphs are visible and it is clear more languages follow. It will probably still need a read more link, but at least now it is clear what it is about. The title of the paragraph can start with the language or language code:


Español: ...

or

ES: ...

If the language always corresponds to a certain country, you can also add flag icons for quick recognition.

 Español: ...

This is not advisable if the language is not per se related to a certain country. You can just hope someone from the US would be interested as well when seeing this:

 English: ...

